# Recursive autoreload of python module

Tags: cvxpy

Autoreload in iPython works only one layer. Is there a way to autoreload recursively?

If module A imports module B, and my notebook imports module A. When I change module B, it doesn't autoreload. Is there a way to change this behaviour?